# Can I have old gnome 2 in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

how can I install old gnome-2 in Ubuntu 11.10?

I'm aware of gnome-session-fallback but I don't like it: no system menu, large panel, effects are not working, and (most important) lack of configuration programs and ugly theme.

And I can't stay on 11.04 because of this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/837212 that is fixed in kernel 3.0

So I need to install Ubuntu 11.10 to use the new kernel but I want to have old gnome-2 desktop and old gnome-2 programs.

I tried to just install kernel 3 from Ubuntu ppa but VirtualBox is not working with that kernel... It's strange because it works in Ubuntu 11.10 with the same kernel.

I tried to revert to 10.04 but it feels slow for me.

I really don't have time for Unity/Gnome Shell/Gnome 3 tweaking, I just want to continue my work and have a stable system without additional headache.

Comment: Have a relook at the gnome-classic question - effects now work.  Other than that the simple answer is no - no way of getting gnome 2.  If you want a fantastic traditional interface, look at Xubuntu and Lubuntu - http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Comment: Yes looks like it's the best solution I can have.